# "I want four more" or "I want more four"?

Tags: word-order, ellipsis, determiners, adjective-order

What's the natural order in the following sentence? Where should I put the word "more" in the following sentences?

My friend told me that we have already 4 oranges. I want to tell him that:

> Okay, but I want **more** four.

or

> Okay, but I want four **more**.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is correct. It may help to put the sentence together with a noun - in this case **oranges** - after the word *more*.

If you were to analyse "I want four more" with traditional prescriptive formal grammars, it would be incomplete. *More* does not stand on its own. You must want more (of) *something*. In the sort of situation you describe, what you 'want more of' is obvious, so it doesn't need saying, but the structure of the sentence still fits as if it were there.

"I want more four" means that *four* is the thing you want more of.

Comment: And "four" is not a mass noun.

Comment: Even prescriptive grammars allow for implied words.

Comment: @it could be if it was a label for a referent of some sort. Like you were eating mystery meals that were labelled with numbers. And if it were capitalised and had no space, it would be a British TV channel.